# Joining outputs from switches

Tags: c

I was wondering if there is a way to join the outputs of switches into one variable, i.e 
say i have switch 1, switch 2, switch 3 and switch 4, each switch is declared separately
the outputs on the switches are
switch 1 -0
switch 2 -1
switch 3 -1 
switch 4 -0

and i want to join these output into one variable e.g. switch_output = 0110
and then i want to change this into a natural number.

is this possible??

Thank you

PS: this is only an example, i'm actually trying to do this with 18 switches, the program i am using, only allows me to declare each switch individually

here is how they are declared

```
static  const gpio_pin_t SW0 = { .port = 2, .pin = 0};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW1 = { .port = 2, .pin = 1};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW2 = { .port = 2, .pin = 2};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW3 = { .port = 2, .pin = 3};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW4 = { .port = 2, .pin = 4};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW5 = { .port = 2, .pin = 5};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW6 = { .port = 2, .pin = 6};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW7 = { .port = 2, .pin = 7};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW8 = { .port = 2, .pin = 8};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW9 = { .port = 2, .pin = 9};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW10 = { .port = 2, .pin = 10};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW11 = { .port = 2, .pin = 11};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW12 = { .port = 2, .pin = 12};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW13 = { .port = 2, .pin = 13};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW14 = { .port = 2, .pin = 14};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW15 = { .port = 2, .pin = 15};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW16 = { .port = 2, .pin = 16};
static  const gpio_pin_t SW17 = { .port = 2, .pin = 17};
```

Mahmoud Fayez
i tried your solution and it works to a certain point, what i get back it a natural number and not a binary number 
here is a print screen of the output [image: print screen]

and here is the code, i did had to modify it a bit to make it work

```
     for (i = 0; i < SwitchesCount; i++)
 {
     temp2 = GPIO_Get(Switches[i]);
     iResult = (iResult << 1) + temp2;
     printf ("%lu, ",temp2);
 }
printf ("\n iResult =  %lu \n",iResult);

static uint32_t iResult = 0;
```

uint32_t is unsigned long

Comment: actually can it be using shifting and boolean e.g s1=1,s2=0,s3=1 s_com = (s1<<1)|s2 and so on

Comment: On what platform is this (what processor, what OS if any, what compiler, anything else that might be relevant)? And what exactly are you trying to do? Read the values of all the pins and combine them in a single integer?

Comment: yes exactly what im trying to do, i'm using a simulator program for a TTE32 microcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const int SwitchesCount = 18;
int iResult = 0;
int i = 0;

static  const gpio_pin_t switches[SwitchesCount] = {{ .port = 2, .pin = 0}, { .port = 2, .pin = 1},{ .port = 2, .pin = 2}, { .port = 2, .pin = 3}, { .port = 2, .pin = 4}, { .port = 2, .pin = 5}, { .port = 2, .pin = 6}, { .port = 2, .pin = 7}, { .port = 2, .pin = 8}, { .port = 2, .pin = 9},{ .port = 2, .pin = 10}, { .port = 2, .pin = 11}, { .port = 2, .pin = 12}, { .port = 2, .pin = 13}, { .port = 2, .pin = 14}, { .port = 2, .pin = 15}, { .port = 2, .pin = 16}, { .port = 2, .pin = 17}};

for (i = 0; i < SwitchesCount; i++)
{
    iResult = iResult << 1 + switches[i]; 
}
// you now have iResult with the value you are looking for.
```