# Converting an array into an integer

Tags: c

Is there a way to convert an array to an integer, i have the follow method but it does not seem to work:

```
int8_t x_array[18] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1};
int32_t numb;

for (int8_t j=0;j<19;j++)
{
   numb = numb + pow(2, i)*x_array[i];
}
```

Is there a reason for this??

**PS:** this is a follow up question from a previous question I had posted
[Joining outputs from switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122100/joining-outputs-from-switches)
I have edited the question to say why the method suggested is not working.

In essence what I am trying to do is create a program, in  RAPIDILITTE which is a simulator software,  to sample a PS input (proximity sensor system) every millisecond which is 18-bit digital input. The input is represented  by toggle switches 0-17(18-bits) which is located on port 2. the input need to be normalised between 0-9999)

The main problem is that( which I have mentioned in the previous posted question) I can only access one pin at a time and not the read the whole port at once. I have tried many ways to read the pins and combine them into one variable convert it to a natural number and then normalise the input. In the end I believe the best way to do this is to put the each pins reading into a `array[18]` and then covert this into a variable and then normalise it.

Comment: BTW, it should be `j<18` and not `j<19`.

Comment: several problems in the question: `i` is *not* declared, `for` loop iterating beyond array limits [should be `j<18`]. Correct and repost...

Comment: yes i see the problem really sorry about that, as u can see i posted this question like 6am i was up most of the night trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numb` is never initialized. You're also iterating past the last element in the array (`j < 19` should be `j< 18`). Additionally, you never declared `i`... it appears you meant `j`.

I believe you're trying to convert the array of bits into a single `int32_t`. Presumably the array is in ascending order of significance i.e. from least- to most-significant bit.

```
int8_t x_array[18] = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
int32_t numb = 0;
for (int8_t j = 0; j < 18; ++j) {
  numb |= x_array[j] << j;
}
```

You don't need to use `pow` here, since `pow(2, j)` is equivalent to `1 << j`.

Comment: you've "out of range" in the loop

Comment: @fasked yes I've corrected that; it was a problem in the original code.

Comment: of course it's just example but we need avoid magic numbers using macro or following construction: `unsigned int size = sizeof(x_array)/sizeof(array[0]);`
Also it needs assertion if size of array will be more than 32: `assert(size <= sizeof(numb) * CHAR_BIT)`.

Comment: @fasked I leave that as an exercise to the reader. PS `int32_t` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize your variable, so reading it is plain **undefined behaviour**. You should say:

```
int32_t numb = 0;
```

You should also decide whether you want `i` or `j` as your loop variable.

(Computing the power each time is also wasteful; instead, you should keep a running multiplier and double it at each step.)

Comment: Hehehe... The whole code is computing power waste itself! (Just joking!) Code written properly written are sooooooo unoptimized (that is, code that demonstrate how things work fundamentally)

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys mentioned, your problem is that you have not initilized numb and that leads to undefined bahaviour of your program.
Also you're loop counter needs to be changed to `i` rather than `j` !

I just wanted to add one other modification to your program and that's how you've been calculating the final result. How about this ? It need much less operation to get the answer :

```
numb = 0;
for (int8_t i=LEN;i>0;i--)
    numb = numb*2 + x_array[i-1];
```